# Temporary rows added by custom-action are ignored by WriteRegistryValues

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action

I'm writing a WIX script.

I have a custom-action that adds rows dynamically to the Registry table:

```
function AddRegistry() 
{
    var registryView = Session.Database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM Registry");
    registryView.Execute();

    var record = Session.Installer.CreateRecord(6);
    record.StringData(1) = "Unique123456";
    record.IntegerData(2) = 2;
    record.StringData(3) = "Software";
    record.StringData(4) = "my_registry_string";
    record.StringData(5) = "value";
    record.StringData(6) = "MyComponent";

    registryView.Modify(7, record); //InsertTemporary
    registryView.Close();

    return 1; //Ok
}
```

The custom-action is scheduled to run as "immediate" and before the "WriteRegistryValues" action:

```
<CustomAction Id="AddRegistry" BinaryKey="CustomActionJS" 
              JScriptCall="AddRegistry" 
              Execute="immediate" Impersonate="no" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="AddRegistry" Before="WriteRegistryValues" />
    <Custom Action="CheckRegistry" After="WriteRegistryValues" />
...
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I've added a 2nd custom-action that enumerates the Registry table, and shows all the entries just find (fixed and temporary).

However, when the WriteRegistryValues is being executed (it is deferred, as far as I understand), it only writes the fixed entries. My dynamic entries are ignored, and not added to the registry.

A fixed Registry entry to the same registry path works fine:

```
<Component Id="MyComponent">
    <RegistryValue Id="Unique11111" Root="HKLM" Key="Software" 
                   Name="my_fixed_value" Value="my_value" 
                   Action="write" Type="string"/>
</Component>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK!

I figured it our - the CA that adds rows to the Registry table must run before **InstallValidate** (which runs before **WriteRegistryValues**)

so changing

```
<Custom Action="AddRegistry" Before="WriteRegistryValues" />
```

to

```
<Custom Action="AddRegistry" Before="InstallValidate" />
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way using a generic method: (Example is in C# using DTF as ActiveScript Custom Actions such as JScript/VBScript are [not a best practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx) for MSI )

```
private static void InsertRecord(Session session, string tableName, Object[] objects)
{
  Database db = session.Database; 
  string sqlInsertSring = db.Tables[tableName].SqlInsertString + " TEMPORARY";
  session.Log("SqlInsertString is {0}", sqlInsertSring);
  View view = db.OpenView(sqlInsertSring); 
  view.Execute(new Record(objects)); 
  view.Close(); 
}
```

Using it looks like

```
object[] fields = new object[] { .... };
InsertRecord(session, "TableName", fields);
```

Comment: I have c# CA's too, which behave the same. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Nope. Same result:
`object[] fields = new object[] { "Unique1234567", 2,"Software","my_registry_string_c","value","MyComponent"};
InsertRecord(session, "Registry", fields);`
still doesn't work...

Comment: Have you looked at the built MSI in Orca to make sure the table exists?  You may need to use the EnsureTable element to tell the compiler to generate the empty table if you haven't declared any other registry removals in the rest of the installer source code.

Comment: I've declared registry additions (not removals) and they work fine. Just the "temporary" ones don't work.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. Seems like you have the bases covered. What does an MSI log say? Maybe your component names are misaligned or something and the deferred execution operations aren't getting generated.  It gets hard to say without looking and sample data and profiling logs.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It's a big script. I'll try and narrow it down to a sample and post it.

Comment: OK!
I figured it our - the CA that adds rows to the Registry table must run before **InstallValidate** (which runs before **WriteRegistryValues**)

Comment: Hmmm, I wouldn't have thought that.  I know I usually schedule right after CostFinalize since this is all part of the costing process but I'm not aware of the InstallValidate interaction.